# storage of a result in a vector

Tags: c, vector

I have tried to store a result in a vector and then to print all those stored values, I think I'm very far, but that's what I was able to develop until now, I'd like some help on what's wrong and how it could you do it, thank you and good night

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int i;
  int x;
  int vetor[]={};
  int a, b;
  int resultado;

  printf("Quantos resultados esse vetor vai receber tem ? ");
  scanf("%d", &x);
  printf("\n");
  for(i=1; i<=x; i++){
      printf("Digite valores para serem somados e armazenados no vetor:\n");
      scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
      resultado = a+b;
      resultado = *vetor;
      printf("vetor contém: %d\n", *vetor);
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("você conseguiu !!!");

  return 0;
}
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````´´´´
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: can you translate the strings in your source code as well? my spanish (I think that's spanish? maybe Portuguese?) is not so great.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))
#define ARRAY_SSIZE(arr) ((ptrdiff_t)ARRAY_SIZE(arr))


int main(void)
{
        ptrdiff_t x;
        int a, b;
        int resultado;

        printf("Quantos resultados esse vetor vai receber tem ? ");
        scanf("%ti", &x);

        int vector[x] = {0};

        printf("\n");

        for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SSIZE(vector); i++) {
                printf("Digite valores para serem somados e armazenados no vetor:\n");
                scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
                resultado = a + b;
                vector[i] = resultado;
                printf("vetor contém: %d\n", vetor[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("você conseguiu !!!\n");

        return 0;
}
```

You should give the array (not vector) a size (`x` in this case) to create it.

Assignments (`a = b;`) work this way: the program calculates whatever is on the right hand side, and copies that value into the variable that is on the left hand side of the =.

When you use (access, write, ...) an array, you have to specify the index (position) of the array you want to use.

It is better to use `sizeof` to calculate the size of an array for loop limits so that if you change the declaration of the array, the code still works (see `ARRAY_SIZE`, and `ARRAY_SSIZE` which is a signed version, so that comparison is done between integers of the same sign, to avoid unexpected bugs).

Always end your last `printf` with a `\n`, so that it doesn't get mixed with other text in the terminal.